# Reading a text file with specific code tag information in php

Tags: php, sql, tags

I would like to read a file, generally a text file, each record is starting with a with a specific code (filed name) in the line  and ended by another specific code for a complete record. Each specific code is  delimited by character ^ as its value in php into dump into sql database.
text file e.g.

001^UK2000009
008^S54/01/R/M/X,
009^Male
110^text1
200^text2
001^UK2000008
008^S54/012/R/M/X
009^Female
110^text1a
200^text2a
and so on...

This is similar to php  constructor File_MARC
thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your current code progress.

Comment: Yes please show some code, and also please clarify what your objective is. Do you want to convert it into a multidimensional array? Do you want to insert it to a SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to read a file with file methods in php and than you can get a specific column name and it's value by below way

First read a single line from a file and than use a explode method to break that line into different elements with space delimitation.

```
$columns = explode(' ', $line_variable);
```

After generating columns I can see that each key values are delimited by ^ (cap) symbol so for that also we can use the explode method.

```
$newColumn =[];
foreach($columns as $column){
    $splited = explode('^', $column);
    $newColumn[][$splited[0]] = $splited[1];
}

print_r($newColumn);
```

This is just to give you an idea that how you can achieve your task but rest is completely dependent on you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and come back with result.

Comment: Be sure to use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES ` flag on `file()`, otherwise you'll have to trim each value to remove the trailing newlines.